# mySQL finding available book and loaning it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a library system and i'm trying to set up a procedure which allows you to enter an isbn and student number and from that it checks the database to see if the book is available if it is, book it. If not then give an error message.

My tables are as follows:

- book - pk_isbn, author, title
- copy - pk_code, duration, fk_isbn
- loan - fk_code, fk_no, pk_taken, due, return_date
- student - pk_no, name, school, allowedtobook

Here is what i currently have code wise *some is just sorta pseudo code i guess as it doesn't work at all currently.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE issue_loan (IN book_isbn CHAR(17), IN stu_no INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE availablebooks INT;
DECLARE allowedtobook BIT;

SET availablebooks = (SELECT DISTINCT
        c.isbn
    FROM
        loan l
            INNER JOIN
        student s ON l.no = s.no
            INNER JOIN
        copy c ON l.code = c.code
    WHERE
        return_date IS NOT NULL);

IF(availablebooks = book_isbn) AND s.embargo = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO loan VALUES
(code, stu_no, CURDATE(), CURDATE()+c.duration,'');
ELSE 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '450000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='no Books Available';
END IF;

END$$
```

The part which return_date IS NOT NULL should be correct as it finds any books which haven't been returned yet. Meaning they're currently booked out.

Comment: There really isn't anything procedural here, is there? You don't need a procedure. You just need a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a variable to a query result set, a variable can only hold one value. You should simply add the comparison with `book_isbn` and `s.embargo = 0` to the query.

```
SET @book_available = (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM loan l
    INNER JOIN student s ON l.no = s.no
    INNER JOIN copy c ON l.code = c.code
    WHERE c.fk_isbn = book_isbn AND s.embargo = 0 AND l.return_date IS NULL);

IF @book_available
THEN 
    INSERT INTO loan (fk_code, fk_no, pk_taken, due, return_date)
    VALUES (code, stu_no, CURDATE(), CURDATE()+c.duration,'');
ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='no Books Available';
END IF
```

Comment: Thank you I knew I was sort of on track with the logic but I'm so new to sql that Im not fully aware of the syntax yet. I'll test this out now and see how it goes

Comment: Actually one thing i forgot to mention, how do i set the SIGNAL correctly? i get an error "bad SQLSTATE" i just want the error message to return if the conditions of the IF statment aren't met.

Hm, i have deleted the signal for now and everything works without errors but if i enter the ISBN of the book i want to loan out and the student number nothing is updated i get the output : "Call issue_loan(235235235, 2333)" but nothing is being inserted into the loan table. Even if the book is actually available.

Comment: I think 450000 may just be too high. The example in the manual uses 45000, maybe it's limited to 5 digits.

Comment: I have now got it working, just got some logic to figure out with the signals but overall everything is working as intended. Thanks a lot.

The tip i had said that i should look at loops and cursors to do this, however I'm not sure that's necessary. Do you see anywhere where either could be used?